# Can preposterousness stifle giggles? Is "preposterousness" part of an adjunct?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, subjects

> The preposterousness of the situation was simply too strange, too unreal, too funny to stifle the uncontrollable giggles.

This sentence is from a book by a New York Times and USA Today bestselling author (Mari Carr). Does it work syntactically? Isn't "the preposterousness of the situation" the subject and the thing that *stifles* "uncontrollable giggles"? Can the sentence be parsed differently?

The meaning of the sentence seems confused as well. The absurdness of the situation was too strange/absurd? Does this line fail semantically as well?

Comment: It relies on the imagination: The preposterousness ... was simply too strange ...  *for anyone* to stifle the uncontrollable giggles. Or, "It was stupid. We laughed. Any questions?"

Comment: It's just fine. *The situation was too strange [for us] to stifle the uncontrollable giggles. The room was too dark [for us] to see the furniture.*

Comment: @desmo It's part of the subject, "the preposterousness of the situation". Grammatically and semantically the sentence is fine.

Comment: Isn't "the preposterousness of the situation" the subject and the thing that stifles "uncontrollable giggles"=No. It's the preposterousness that makes stifling impossible.

Comment: _Too strange for X to VP,_ is **negative**, part of a construction meaning _so strange that VP is not possible_.  The word _preposterousness_ is ungainly but understandable, so it's OK (whereas *preposterousdom and *preposterosity aren't).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is the [agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_(grammar)) of the infinitive verb "to stifle". Because the writer does not explicitly identify an agent, the reader may assume that it is the sentence's subject ("the preposterousness"). As you say, that doesn't seem to make sense. The reader is apparently supposed to infer that the agent is . . . someone. Assuming that it is the author, the sentence could have been written more clearly as:

> The preposterousness of the situation was simply too strange, too unreal, too funny **for me** to stifle the uncontrollable giggles.

(This sentence is similar to suggestions made in a couple of comments above.)

---

I don't see anything wrong with "preposterousness" being "too strange, too unreal, too funny". If the latter words were exact synonyms for "preposterous", then there might be a problem (somewhat akin to saying that someone's weight was too heavy), but I think that they're different enough not to worry about it.

Comment: Great answer! I see what you did with your last line. "I think that they're different enough (for us) not to worry about it" :)

Comment: @desmo Oh, neat! I wasn't even aware I'd done that.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, this construction is irreproachable; the semantics is another matter.  First, we are presented with the notion that strangeness, unreality and  amusiveness are characteristics, not of the situation, as we might normally expect it, but of the prepostorousness of it, and that does get one thinking; what can that be meant to say ? Are we confronted to a very abstruse concept or is there nothing more to be seen in this type of description other than the usual characterizing of a situation that has been expressed in a rather extravagant manner, perhaps a manner not well thought out? I opt for the latter.

Next the reader is confronted to the idea that what usually gives way to a certain situation when present in sufficient amounts, when not present in sufficient amounts operates a control on the phenomena, and this is aberrant: plainly, it has no effect and there is no exercice of any control.

In my opinion the concepts used by that writer, in that sentence, are wrongly interrelated, are not interrelated realistically; the relations implied do not exist in the real world.